# Mockito method returns null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testng, mockito

I looked in the forum but couldn't find why this would happen

I have

```
public class AImpl implements A{

   @Autowired
   B bImpl;

   protected void doSomething(){
      String s = "test";
      String d = b.permuteString(s);
      System.out.println(s.substring(1));
   }

}

public class BImpl implements B{
    public String permuateString(s){
     return s;
   }
}
```

In the test I have:

```
@InjectMocks
AImpl aImpl;

@Mock
BImpl bImpl;

@Test
public void testCode(){
testCode(){
   aImpl.doSomething();
}
}
```

The method `permuateString` from `BImpl` always returns null. I need to know the result of permuteString() in order to continue the execution of doSomething. so it can't be null

Why is it?

I am using `Mockito`

Comment: `b.permuateString(s)` should throw a `NullPointerException` if `B b` wasn't assigned.

Comment: sorry I meant b is bImpl and it's being Autowired. I see when debugging testng that it's not null

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By annotating the `BImpl` field with `@Mock`, you're saying that the instance itself should be a mock. However, you're not telling Mockito what result the mock should give when invoked with arguments, so Mockito uses its default behaviour of returning null.

The fact that `BImpl` is a real class with real behaviour is irrelevant. The field does not contain an instance of that class; it contains an instance of a mock.

In your test method, before you call `aImpl.doSomething()`, tell mockito the behaviour you expect it to use:

```
when(bImpl.permuteString("test")).thenReturn("someOtherValue");
```

Comment: What if bImpl arguments (the "test") is being computed as part of a.doSomething() which I can't predict in advance?

Comment: @Odelya Consider what you're trying to test: the behaviour of AImpl, and how that interacts with its dependency, B. If all you care about is that AImpl gave the B class *something*, then use verify() in Mockito to ensure it was called.

Comment: Let me explain more. A is a class that sends emails. B is a class that knows to retrieve HTML (which was created in A) and convert it to image, so A would send it in the email. When A retrieves the results, it rotates the image and saves it to disk. So I need B to be executed.

Comment: @Odelya You need B to be executed, but as it's a mock, you really only need to be sure that it was executed and provided *some* valid value. That's what you set up in Mockito. It doesn't have to be the correct value for the input, just an acceptable one.

Test that the real BImpl does provide correct answers in the unit test for that class; not in this one.

Comment: While I was looking meanwhile in the web I saw that I can use RETURNS_MOCKS which mocks a new object (at least I won't get null response). What do you think about it?

Comment: @Odelya From what little I know of your code, RETURNS_MOCKS seems unnecessary. Return a pre-canned value instead.

Comment: do you mean that when checking one resource, I need to know the "code" inside in order to see that it's working fine? I want to do black box tests. I don't care what code is in inside

Comment: @Odelya No, I'm saying that if your method-under-test depends on the value returned by a (mock) collaborator, then you need to provide a reasonable value to be returned by said (mock) collaborator. That is, your test can't (usually) ignore dependencies. However, the value provided from that (mock) collaborator can be pre-canned so that your method-under-test is being tested in isolation and does not need to know about the real implementation of the collaborator; that would be tested separately.

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the `B` instance being `@Autowired` into your `AImpl` instance is also a mock (whether it's a mock `B` or a mock `BImpl`, I don't know).

In either case, the default stub method for any mock will probably return `null` unless you tell it otherwise (unless you `stub` it).

I can't be certain (unless I run my own tests), but I can say that it'll help for you to simply add logging statements (or use a debugger) to verify whether:

a.) What value does `AImpl#b` contain (is it a `BImpl` or a mock `B`)?

b.) Whether `BImpl#permuateString()` gets called.

c.) What value `BImpl#permuateString()` gets for `s`

Comment: A) I fixed my mistake. AImpl contains mock of B which is bImpl (see in the test - I declare it as Mock and inject it). B) when invoking doSomething C) I can't know in advance. It's something irrelevant to the tests but the result should never be null